# PHP function does not get called

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter

I'm trying out Codeigniter with AngularJS and I'm creating a simple login page. The problem I'm experiencing is that the PHP function "user_logout_process" does not get called

**HTML Code**

```
<section id="login">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-wrap" ng-app="validationApp">
                        <form name="userForm" method="POST" ng-controller="mainController" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate> <!-- novalidate prevents HTML5 validation since we will be validating ourselves -->
                            <h1>Log in with your email account</h1>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" name="username" id="name" ng-model="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="key" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" ng-model="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                            </div>

                             <input type="submit" id="btn-login" class="btn btn-custom btn-lg btn-block" value="Log in">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- /.col-xs-12 -->
            </div> <!-- /.row -->
        </div> <!-- /.container -->
    </section>
```

**Angular Code**

```
var validationApp = angular.module('validationApp', []);

        validationApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $http, $location) {

            $scope.submitForm = function() {

                $http({

                    method: 'POST',
                    url: "authentication/user_login_process",
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                    data: JSON.stringify({email:$scope.email,password:$scope.password})

                }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    console.log("success" + response.data);
                    console.log(JSON.stringify({email:$scope.email,password:$scope.password}));
                    //$location.path('authentication/user_login_process');

                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    alert( "failure message: " + JSON.stringify({email:$scope.email,password:$scope.password}));

                });

            };

        }]);
```

**PHP Code**

```
class Authentication extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();

            // Load form helper library
            $this->load->helper('form');

            // Load form validation library
            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            // Load session library
            $this->load->library('session');

            $this->load->model('user_model');
    }


    public function view($page = 'login'){

            if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php')){
                    show_404();
            }
            $this->load->view('pages/login');

    }

    public function logout(){
            $this->session->sess_destroy();
            $data = array(
            'error_message' => 'Logout Successful');
            $this->load->view('pages/login', $data);
    }

    public function user_login_process() {

            echo "test";

            print_r(json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')));

            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(1);</script>";

            return "data 1";
     }
```

}

When I inspect the elements, I see that the post was able to push through but nothing happens on the page after the button press, see bottom part of the image. I have commented and taken out most of the code on user_login_process (database connection) to test whether the function in invoked. Any Ideas?

[image]

Comment: Can see from your screenshot that the content-length of the response is 127 characters. What is in the response?

Comment: status is successful what is in response tab?